# 'Executable named git not found on path:' when running stack

Tags: haskell-stack

After a recent change in the repository that I am working, I can no longer build. When trying to run any `stack` command, such as `stack build`, I get the following error:

```
$ stack build
Executable named git not found on path: ["/home/matthew/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-nix/lts-8.23/8.0.2/bin","/nix/store/kikxl1m9gg1rh9yfi9ly9bkl39zdb6z7-postgresql-9.5.6/bin","/nix/store/xczvw3rlvr1ind8s88i7yx0vasl4gzxm-ghc-8.0.2/bin","/nix/store/sxngsdy5y53j8fkb912hbpgamb2bpv5q-patchelf-0.9/bin","/nix/store/9ngvanddznmrbf74cvy0pmrqimk3i56x-paxctl-0.9/bin","/nix/store/c07gdr6cm43j1cphadzafq185k711vx4-coreutils-8.26/bin","/nix/store/7pyzxi7k5l6nym972gi2nq8s9f9b2q0j-findutils-4.6.0/bin","/nix/store/gjwa02cchnj2r69dlqjixjmdn0ws7f1v-diffutils-3.5/bin","/nix/store/xk38vw7z7bfr8173vdwfrfamxqcaj7hi-gnused-4.4/bin","/nix/store/r6s8rcd28wsk4gwviyc93343bq5zwlqq-gnugrep-3.0/bin","/nix/store/bvs3nyfflhsb75cfn4ff2a6xnksdzx9f-gawk-4.1.3/bin","/nix/store/g3skr3kss1fqqzl5viyg178qbcp4cdky-gnutar-1.29/bin","/nix/store/kdx0bwfy20q6blpgpdb7psbn1y435r56-gzip-1.8/bin","/nix/store/f2fg211g8zy5k624dwx0g7z32cm148mr-bzip2-1.0.6.0.1-bin/bin","/nix/store/adjkz7lhgvl3y3hpkzfsmpk15f0jrnmr-gnumake-4.2.1/bin","/nix/store/lpk84rsbha199vm3k54498lqv2jswqj8-bash-4.4-p5/bin","/nix/store/1hdv6h68f7xy9k0lhxqf26saz0w0r39i-patch-2.7.5/bin","/nix/store/vkbh4xbgxvx3v9813d4kdwv8ggwrp038-xz-5.2.2-bin/bin"]
```

It seems that my `stack` program does not know the correct path to my `git` program.

How can I specify my `git` path to `stack`?

I have verified that I do have `git` installed at the following path.

```
$ which git
/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin/git
```

I am on nixos 17.03.

---

Edit.

I am sure that the `stack build` and `which git` commands were run in the same environment as they were run back to back in the same shell.

My path is

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/matthew/bin:/run/wrappers/bin:/run/wrappers/bin:/home/matthew/.nix-profile/bin:/home/matthew/.nix-profile/sbin:/home/matthew/.nix-profile/lib/kde4/libexec:/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin:/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/sbin:/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/lib/kde4/libexec:/run/current-system/sw/bin:/run/current-system/sw/sbin:/run/current-system/sw/lib/kde4/libexec
```

This shows the `/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin` is in the path, which contains `git`.

---

Also, in my `stack.yaml` file when I set `system-ghc: true` I get an 'access rights' error instead of the 'Executable named git not found' error.

```
$ stack build
Warning: /home/matthew/backup/azara_work/platform/api/stack.yaml: Unrecognized field in NixOptsMonoid: system-ghc
Cloning into '/home/matthew/backup/azara_work/platform/api/.stack-work/downloaded/4FnxEtHDACVR'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Process exited with ExitFailure 128: /nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin/git clone --recursive git@github.com:seanhess/rollbar-haskell.git /home/matthew/backup/azara_work/platform/api/.stack-work/downloaded/4FnxEtHDACVR
```

Comment: Stack just adds to the PATH. It seems like `/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin/` is not on the PATH - it is not in the list.  Are you sure stack is being run in the same environment as which?  Might be helpful to do `echo $PATH` to be sure, see how it deviates from the PATH that stack is using.

Comment: @mgsloan thank you for the comment. I have edited the question including results of `echo $PATH` as suggested. Also I have found that when enabling `system-ghc` in my `stack.yaml` file (as described in the edit), I get an 'access rights' error instead of a 'git not found' error.

Comment: I've got no clue, seems like things are working in very inconsistent ways with your setup.  Setting system-ghc shouldn't make any difference for finding the git binary.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to either `~/.stack/config.yaml`
or local `stack.yaml` (if it already has a nix: block)

```
   nix:
    enable: true
    packages: [git]
```